# Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform on windows 2008 server system

Tags: java, dll

Today when i migrate a project from old server to new server, i encounter this problem when i test the deployed service codes. 
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: E802: Can't load shared library. E:\Rochade\bin\msvcr71.dll E:\Rochade\bin\msvcr71.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
no msvcr71 in java.library.path

i googled it on the internet and found some tips on installing a 36 bit jdk, i tried but didn't sovle the problem, does any one has any comment on this? i am really in hurry to get this problem solved, which is the road block for us moving forward on the migration process.

Comment: What is a "36 bit jdk"? You mean 32-bit, do you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot load library compiled for 32-bit architecture in 64-bit environment.

Solution is to recompile the library for x64 or obtain 64-bit version if you do not have its sources.

Answer (score 0):

You either can use a 32-bit JVM or install the 64-bit version of the Microsoft Visual Studio C/C++ Redistributable Package.
Or better reinstall the software on the new server. Moving only the folders to a new computer is not a good idea on Windows, especially when the old PC was a 32-bit system and the new PC is a 64-bit system.